# Would it be possible to inject service into singleton class c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dependency-injection

I wonder what would be correct way to inject services into singleton class (by using NInject framework, for example.

What singleton code is doing actually - it run windows form in application context

```
public class FrontController
{
    private static volatile FrontController _instance;
    private static readonly object syncRoot = new Object();
    private ControlsContainer _controlsContainer;

    private FrontController() { }

    public static FrontController Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        _instance = new FrontController();
                    }

                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public void StartApplication()
    {
        _controlsContainer = new ControlsContainer();
        Application.Run(_controlsContainer);
    }

    public void EndApplication()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    internal void Synchronize()
    {
        ISymantecService<ClientModel> service =
            new SymantecService<ClientModel>(new CustomerRepository<ClientModel>());

        service.Synchronize();
    }
}
```

We have

```
 public void StartApplication()
 {
        _controlsContainer = new ControlsContainer();
        Application.Run(_controlsContainer);
 }
```

as well as

```
internal void Synchronize()
{
    ISymantecService<ClientModel> service =
            new SymantecService<ClientModel>(new CustomerRepository<ClientModel>());

    quickBookservice.Synchronize();
}
```

Is there any way to inject ISymantecService and ICustomerRepository in this class in a thread safe manner.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. If you're using some sort of dependency injection, make this an instance class and tell the container to use the lifetime mechanism of a singleton.

Comment: @Yuval can you clarify why it would be a bad idea?

Comment: Other than the fact that I think singletons are a giant mutable anti-pattern, how would you pass these dependencies? Any attempt would be a terrible hack.

Comment: Actually that was my question. Either way I have to figure out how to apply dependency injection on win forms technology - this singleton is controller of the MVC pathern we applied on win forms technology.